# Get a list of data from Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

Filling the dictionary with two arrays. I don't know how to get a list of data from it using foreach. Example: a 17,  l 16 .... Please tell me how to do this?

```
string[] words = { "a", "l", "c", "d", "h", "o", "t" };
int[] times = { 17, 16, 1, 02, 11, 19, 21 };
Dictionary<string[], int[]> data= new Dictionary<string[], int[]>();
data.Add(words, times);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string[], int[]> pair in data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Value: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
        }

// output: Key: System.String[], Value: System.Int32[]
```

Comment: what do you mean by list of data?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you mean that you want to populate dictionary with that data? In what form? For each word as key to put all the numbers as values? For each work have a single number as a value? And what have you tried?

Comment: You likely do not want a `Dictionary<string[], int[]>` you want a `Dictionary<string, int>`

Comment: currently you only have one pieve of data in it. Its key is `{ "a", "l", "c", "d", "h", "o", "t" };` and its data is  `{ 17, 16, 1, 02, 11, 19, 21 }` You can access the list of keys in your dict by `data.Keys` -  a single data item by `var oneDataItem = dict[the key you want to access];` and all values stored in the dictionary by `dict.Values`. You can use `foreach (var k in data.Keys) { Console.WriteLine( data[k]); }` to do something with every key stored inside the dict. You need to practice C# and read up on [Dict-Msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Also : you probably don't want to use `data.Values` - if you do need to, its probably a sign that a dictionary is not a well choosen data container.

Comment: I made edits, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From your example it seems like you are looking for a `Dictionary<string,int>` where for each index i you want the key to be the i'th item in `words` and the value to be the i'th item in `times`.

A `foreach` approach will be:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string,int>();
for(int i = 0; i < words.Lenth; i++)
{
    dict.Add(words[i], times[i];
}
```

*Notice that this assumes that `times` as at least the same amount of times as `words` and if not will result in an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.*

A linq approach will be:

```
// C# 7.0
var dict = words.Zip(times, (w,t) => (w,t)).ToDictionary(key => key.w, value => value.t);

// C# prior to 7.0
var dict = words.Zip(times, (w,t) => new { w,t })
                .ToDictionary(key => key.w, value => value.t);
```

*Notice that `Zip` will return the items by the collection with the lower count.*